# What is equivalent of <bean:define> in struts 2

Tags: java, struts2

Below is the line of codes written in struts1 JSP page, and what to convert it into Struts2 JSP page.

```
<%@ taglib uri="/tags/struts-html" prefix="html" %>
<%@ taglib uri="/tags/struts-bean" prefix="bean" %>

<bean:define id="clientOptions" name="XYZ" property="clients" type="java.util.Iterator"/>

<html:select name="XYZ" property="id" onfocus="SCV(this.selectedIndex)" onchange="selectClient(this)">
     <html:options collection="clientOptions" labelProperty="name" property="id" />
</html:select>
```

Can anybody please tell me, what is the equivalent code in struts2?

Comment: `<html:bean/>` is `<s:bean>`, and `<html:select>`/`<html:option>` is just `<s:select>`, and you probably will need only `<s:select>`, with no s:bean at all.

Comment: @Rahul You shouldn't use all code from the snippet to find equivalents for every tag in Struts2. See my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use:

```
<s:set var="newVariable" value="bean.property"/>
```

here you have the doc:

http://struts.apache.org/release/2.3.x/docs/set.html

Answer (score 0):

The equivalent code is

```
<s:set var="clientOptions" value="%{XYZ.clients}"/>
<s:select name="clients" list="%{#clientOptions}" listKey="id" listValue="name" onfocus="SCV(this.selectedIndex)" onchange="selectClient(this)"/>
```

Comment: You only need getters to access bean property via OGNL.